# Only the top UIViewController is auto resizing on rotation, others on the navigation stack are not

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, orientation

My setup is a UINaviagtionController controlling a stack of UIViewControllers, with Portrait, Landscape Left and Landscape Right ticked
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4WuL.png)

I have ViewControllerA in portrait mode and add ViewControllerB either via a segue or via

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newMenuViewController animated:YES];
```

Whilst on ViewControllerB I rotate the device to landscape and then pop ViewControllerB, when ViewControllerA is displayed it is still in portrait mode with black covering the rest of the screen (I can only assume this is the UIWindow).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RADZv.png)

Can't seem to recreate the problem in a new project.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot, the View *rotated* but didn't resize... Check your constraints and/or autoresizing masks.

Comment: Thanks but checked all these, no luck. probably should have mentioned that this is app wide, happens to every ViewController, but yes good spot on the rotated and resize thing, never really thought of it like.

Comment: Probably should also mention that viewControllerB does resize and rotate, it's only the others on the stack that don't

Comment: Hmmm... Did you subclass UINavigationController? There's gotta be something going on. Search your code for any of these three:  shouldAutorotate ... supportedInterfaceOrientations ... preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation

Comment: I subclassed UINavigationController to try and solve the issue with no luck, and also none of those are in my code

Comment: This is the kind of thing that would drive me batty until I figured it out... Do you have it in a small, inconsequential project that I could grab? Or is it just in a large project you can't share?

Comment: It's a very large project that I'm unable to share, I have a temporary fix which is to set self.view's frame in viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: it's still rather annoying because this fix shouldn't need to be here, but it works for now.